# Verify and Publish Contract on Etherscan with Imported OpenZeppelin file

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, etherscan

I'm currently building a ERC721 compliant contract and have published the contract here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa513bc0a0d3af384fefcd8bbc1cc0c9763307c39 - I'm now attempting to verify and publish the contract source code

The start of my file looks like so:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// We will be using Solidity version 0.8.4
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract ViperToken is ERC721 {
```

However, when attempting to verify and publish with a Solidity single file I have the following error appear:

```
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:6:1:
  |
6 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can anyone point me in the direction to either 1. Solve this problem or 2. Documentation on how to appropriately write a contract that has dependencies imported that can be verified with Etherscan. Right now this is just a single file contract.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put I had to go down a rabbit hole to work this out as I'm pretty new to Solidity.

I had to do the following;

1. Learn and use https://www.trufflesuite.com/ to setup a project and put my contract there (Using Ganache helped a lot with testing for anyone new to Solidity too)
2. Use HD Wallet provider package and follow tutorial here to get it on ropsten Etherscan https://medium.com/coinmonks/5-minute-guide-to-deploying-smart-contracts-with-truffle-and-ropsten-b3e30d5ee1e
3. Finally, use truffle-plugin-verify https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify to verify the contract on Etherscan

All in all, I am pretty sure there is no way within the Etherscan web app to verify a contract that contains an imported file.

The final product is here if anyone is interested in seeing how I structured it all https://github.com/lukecurtis93/viper-nft (it's just a CryptoKitties clone I found online as a base and updated it all)

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much for writing down everything which lead you the right way.

Answer (score 6):

If you are compiling into REMIX IDE

1. From REMIX IDE
2. Search for "Flattener" pluging
3. RIght click the file -> Flatten yourcontract.sol
4. Copy/Paste on Etherscan

Comment: There's actually a plugin named "ETHERSCAN - CONTRACT VERIFICATION" which works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I used `npx hardhat flatten` to compile all the code into one page, then copy and paste the code into Etherscan's single file verification. I think it is fine if you are just learning to get a feel for verifying your smart contract in Etherscan. But when it comes to production level code, I think OP's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

`npx hardhat flatten` gives license identifiers error when trying to verify in etherscan.

Solution is to add the below in `hardhat.config.js`

```
 task("flat", "Flattens and prints contracts and their dependencies (Resolves licenses)")
  .addOptionalVariadicPositionalParam("files", "The files to flatten", undefined, types.inputFile)
  .setAction(async ({ files }, hre) => {
    let flattened = await hre.run("flatten:get-flattened-sources", { files });
    
    // Remove every line started with "// SPDX-License-Identifier:"
    flattened = flattened.replace(/SPDX-License-Identifier:/gm, "License-Identifier:");
    flattened = `// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIXED\n\n${flattened}`;

    // Remove every line started with "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" except the first one
    flattened = flattened.replace(/pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;\n/gm, ((i) => (m) => (!i++ ? m : ""))(0));
    console.log(flattened);
  });
```

An then run `npx hardhat flat contracts/ContractToFlatten.sol > Flattened.sol`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this issue in the future and hoping to bypass the truffle/hardhat routes: consider using the Remix Etherscan validation plugin (https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contract_verification.html#etherscan). Alternatively, you can manually upload all your dependencies to Etherscan and adjust the import paths to reference files that are now on the same level as your primary contract.